# JavaFX changing the scene

Tags: java, javafx, scene

I'm coding a  game and I'm using javaFX.

Now every time I change my scene I execute this code:

```
PasAanSchermController keuzeSpeel = new PasAanSchermController(dc, true);
Scene scene = new Scene(keuzeSpeel, 700, 500);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.setTitle("Sokoban");
```

The stage is a constructor parameter (pass by reference?)

I also use this code when I go to the previous scene. I'm guessing this isn't the way it's supposed to be done (because you keep making new scenes)...

If I am indeed wrong doing it this way, please tell me how I should do it.

Many thanks and if my question isn't clear, please comment so I can explain further.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in what you are doing but why do you change your scene?

Comment: U mean I could use stage.getScene = new Scene(keuzespeel,700,500)?

Comment: No,  I didn't mean that. When you make a new scene and the old scene is no longer reference, it will be garbage collected. But, the question is do you really need new scenes or can you handle it by just altering the layout containers?

Comment: i.e. you could do `stage.getScene().setRoot(keuzeSpeel);`, which perhaps has better performance (though it's negligible). There's nothing particularly wrong with your approach, though.

Comment: You want to switch between scenes continuously? Then please look here : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJOza3XQk34